# Post JSON Object RestSharp v107

Tags: json, restsharp

I have to post this json data:

JSON.stringify(dataRest) is:
{**"Ds_MerchantParameters"**:"eyJEU19NRVJDSEFOVF9BTU9VTlQiOiI3Myw4NCIsIkRTX01FUkNIQU5UX0NVUlJFTkNZIjoiOTc4IiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfTUVSQ0hBTlRDT0RFIjoiMzUyNDM0NDM1IiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfT1JERVIiOiIwMDAwMDAwMDA3NjUiLCJEU19NRVJDSEFOVF9JRE9QRVIiOiIxODExNzViOTBjNDM2ZDNlZDQ3ODg4OWEyMjdjNjI2Yjc0MDBiOTEyIiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfVEVSTUlOQUwiOiIxIiwiRFNfTUVSQ0hBTlRfVFJBTlNBQ1RJT05UWVBFIjoiMCJ9",**"Ds_Signature"**:"X5IoP/ssIy+8gBFbD9znLoz4dFOH/mWRjMCaE/8kq65XJJVLywT05wVXE4Fqbbo6",**"Ds_SignatureVersion"**:"HMAC_SHA256_V1"}

To this endpoint https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/rest/trataPeticionREST

Using RestSharp (v107) (or httpclient).

I post above data to my api LaunchRequest via ajax:

```js
$.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: localhost + 'api/Redsys/LaunchRequest',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify(dataRest)
}).done(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
}).fail(function (error) {
    console.error(error.status + '\n' + error.responseText);
});
```

This is the api that receive the above data and launch request to the endpoint:

```js
[HttpPost("LaunchRequest")]
public async Task<string> LaunchRequest(DataRest dataRest)
{
    string strDataRest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataRest);

    var client = new RestClient("https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/");
    var request = new RestRequest("sis/rest/trataPeticionREST", Method.Post);

    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
    request.AddBody(strDataRest);

    var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        return response.Content;
    }
    else
    {
        return response.ErrorMessage;
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Allways receive this message:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (sis-t.redsys.es:25443)

Thank you in advance for your help.

I think one of my mistakes is serialize dataRest.

LaunchRequest should be like this:

```js
 [HttpPost("LaunchRequest")]
 public async Task<string> LaunchRequest(DataRest dataRest)
 {
     var client = new RestClient("https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/");
     var request = new RestRequest("sis/rest/trataPeticionREST", Method.Post);
    
     request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
     request.AddBody(dataRest);
    
     var response = await client.ExecuteAsync(request);
    
     if (response.IsSuccessful)
     {
         return response.Content;
     }
     else
     {
         return response.ErrorMessage;
     }
 }
```

I don't know if the steps I follow in LaunchRequest are correct, but anyway I always get this error message:

A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (sis-t.redsys.es:25443)

Thank you very much again for the help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most probably not related to RestSharp as it looks like a connection issue between the host running your API, and the external API host.

From the other issues, I am not sure why you deserialize the object just to serialize it back. You can just do this:

```
var request = new RestRequest("sis/rest/trataPeticionREST", Method.Post);
request.AddJsonBody(dataRest);
```

You also need to avoid creating the client for each request. Create a single client instance in the controller's constructor.

It's all described in the documentation by the way.